# Grouping the list of list based on the property

Tags: java, list, java-stream

Below are my sample Class Object,

```
class Sample{
String name;
String value;
String id;
}
```

My Input List looks like below,

`[Sample(name=title,` **`value=Title`**`, id=1), Sample(name=input,` **`value=DCE`**`, id=1), Sample(name=output,` **`value=CDE`**`, id=1), Sample(name=title,` **`value=Title`**`, id=2), Sample(name=input,` **`value=DCEE`**`, id=2), Sample(name=output,` **`value=CDEE`**`, id=2), Sample(name=title,` **`value=Title`**`, id=3), Sample(name=input,` **`value=DCEEE`**`, id=3), Sample(name=output,` **`value=CDEEE`**`, id=3)]`

I need to group the list of list based on the id property and display the value alone as the below.

Expected Output:

```
Title DCE CDE 1
Title DCEE CDEE 2
Title DCEEE CDEEE 3
```

Expected Output:

```
{[Title DCE CDE 1],
Title DCEE CDEE 2],
Title DCEEE CDEEE 3]}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, you've failed to ask a question. What do you need? SO is not a code writing service, so start by writing the program and *if and when* you are stuck, you can come here with a *concrete* question that needs fixing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the comments to the original post saying that there's no question here, I think it's clear enough what the OP (original poster) is asking. But there is some uncertainty introduced by the inclusion of two expected outputs. I'm going to assume it's a list of strings, where the string is a concatenation of the Sample.value for each sample with the same id value. (I agree that you should edit the original post to make this clear.)

Assuming the OP meant this (I'll use `record` instead of `class` because it looks like these are immutable objects):

```
    record Sample(
        String name,
        String value,
        String id) {
    }

    Sample[] samples = new Sample[] {
            new Sample("title", "Title", "1"),
            new Sample("input", "DCE", "1"),
            new Sample("output", "CDE", "1"),
            new Sample("title", "Title", "2"),
            new Sample("input", "DCEE", "2"),
            new Sample("output", "CDEE", "2"),
            new Sample("title", "Title", "3"),
            new Sample("input", "DCEEE", "3"),
            new Sample("output", "CDEEE", "3")
        };
```

and the task is to use the Java streaming APIs to get this result:

```
[ "Title DCE CDE 1",
  "Title DCEE CDEE 2", 
  "Title DCEEE CDEEE 3"
]
```

the approach is to use `Collectors.groupingBy(Sample::id)` to initially transform to an intermediate result of a `Map<String, List<Sample>>`

```
1=[Sample[name=title, value=Title, id=1], Sample[name=input, value=DCE, id=1], Sample[name=output, value=CDE, id=1]]
2=[Sample[name=title, value=Title, id=2], Sample[name=input, value=DCEE, id=2], Sample[name=output, value=CDEE, id=2]]
3=[Sample[name=title, value=Title, id=3], Sample[name=input, value=DCEEE, id=3], Sample[name=output, value=CDEEE, id=3]]
```

Note that for each key, the value is a list. In order to extract the `sample.value` from each sample in the list, you would then stream the `entrySet`, map each value by streaming the list and mapping each sample to just the value property (`map(Sample::value)`), and then collect those into a string using `Collectors.joining(" ") + " " + entry.getKey())`. And then you would `.collect(Collectors.toList())` to get your expected output. In pseudo code, you finish the transformation like this:

```
intermediateResult.entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> stream the entry.value samples list
        .map(each sample to just the sample.value)
        .collect(joining with delimiter = " ") and 
                 concatenating " " + entry.getKey() to the end)
    .collect(each of these strings to a list);
```

You could also do this transformation in one statement using `collectingAndThen()`:

```
List<String> result = Arrays.stream(samples)
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            initialTransformer, 
            finishingTransformer));
```

I haven't filled in everything so that you can have the challenge of completing it and gaining a deeper understanding.